# $x \in \mathbb R^d$, $B$(closed)$ \subseteq \mathbb R^d$. Where $\mathbb R^d$ is an inner product space. Proof help

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

$x \in \mathbb R^d$, $B$(closed)$ \subseteq \mathbb R^d$. Where $\mathbb R^d$ is an inner product space.

Show that there exists a point $b_0 \in B$ such that $d(x,B) = \|x - b_0\|$

**My attempt:**

$d(x,B) \le \|x - b\|$ for some $b \in B$ because $d(x,B) = \inf\{\|x-b\|\}$

For a point $b_0 \in B$(closed), does this imply that we can find a point $b_0$ such that it is equal to $\inf\{\|x-b\|\}$?

I feel like I can draw a picture to show this but I can't figure out the right logic to prove it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of very recent question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1130872/115115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that an infimum is always attained for continuous maps defined on *compact* sets. The map you consider can be shown quite directly to be continuous. The set $B$ is closed by definition, yet it might not be compact if it is unbounded.

However, it is "clear" that the infimum cannot be attained at a point far far away. (Yet give a formal argument for this.)

So, you can in fact show that the infimum over $b \in B$ is the same as that over $C$ where $C$ is a closed and *bounded,* whence compact, subset of $B$. Thus the infimum is attained.